# Show that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous in all points $x\in X$ which are not accumulation points of $X$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following task:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a
>   mapping. Show that $f$ is continuous in every $x\in X$ which is not an
>   accumulation point of $X$.

I'm using the following definitions:

**Definition 1:**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a mapping. Mapping $f$ is continuous at point $x_0\in X$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x)\in V$ always when $x\in U$.

**Definition 2:**

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. Point $x\in X$ is called an accumulation point of $A$ if for every neighborhood U of $x$ we have $(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq \emptyset$.

I went on trying to solve this by assuming that $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ and that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $X$. That is for each neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ we have $(U\setminus\{x_0\}) \cap X = U\setminus\{x_0\}$.

How should I proceed, how can I show that $f$ can't be now continuous at $x_0$? Thank you for any help!

Comment: The question is only about points that *are not* accumulation points of $X$; you don’t have to prove anything about points that *are* accumulation points of $X$.

Comment: Aah, funny me...I misread the problem. Sorry about that stupid mistake x) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start with $x_0$ not being an accumulation point of $X$ and then *show* that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ using the definition.

Write down what it means that $x_0$ is not an accumulation point of $X$: for some open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ we have that ....

Now use this $U$ in the definition of continuity.

Comment: Thank you, got it. I somehow misunderstood the problem. Clear now :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Hi Henno, I have one more question to ask :) I tried to solve this now by assuming that $x_0$ is not an accumulation point. That is, there exists neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $(U\setminus \{x_0\}) \cap X =\emptyset$. Because $U\subset X$ this means that $U=\{x_0\}$. I think this means now that $U\cap X=U\neq \emptyset$ for all neighborhoods of $x_0$. I'm not sure why this means that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: @jjepsuomi Well, start from the definition: take any neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$. Now try plugging in $U = \{x_0\}$ (which we now know is open (!) by virtue of not being an accumulation point of $X$)...

Comment: Okay, I'll try and get back to you to confirm if I got it right =) appreciate it

Comment: I tried like this: Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ in $Y$. If for $x_0$ there is a neighborhood $U=\{x_0\}$, then clearly $f(x)\in V$ when $x\in U=\{x_0\}$. So for every point $x\in X$ for which there exists a neighborhood $U=\{x\}$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$. Does this make sense? :)

Comment: Yes, quite. You can always get close to $f(x_0)$ if you can force $x = x_0$, essentially.

Comment: Thank you very much! sorry if I have funny questions, I'm a beginner in topology and some definitions etc. are still a bit unclear here and there. This was a bit confusing problem because the answer seemed too obvious =)

Comment: It shows for instance that if $X = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ then it does not matter how we define $f$ on $2$ for continuity at $2$. We cannot get close to it with other points.

Comment: I see :) Thank you for the example. You've been most helpful!